# Can I tell Neo4j GraphQL to ignore variables if they are null?

Tags: neo4j, graphql

Currently, I have a large mutation that creates `Post`s that could optionally have attributes, which sometimes come in the form of linked nodes. So a post might have a body, created_date, and other properties but might also have a `creator` which is a connected node.

Sometimes these have `rating`s which creates and connects to new `Rating` nodes. The problem is, my mutation accepts these variables either way, so whether I have a value for the rating or not, it seems the mutation will create a new `Rating`. There are other examples, `Rating` is not the only type of connected node that may or may not appear in `Post`s.

So my question is: other than creating a new mutation for every combination of variables (there are very many), is there a way to tell the mutation to totally ignore the field if there's no value submitted?

```
mutation NEW_POST($body: String, $rating: Float) {
  createPosts(input: { body: $body, rating: { create: { node: { value: $rating }}}}){
```

Here is a shortened version of what the NEW_POST looks like. I truncated it for simplicity. Essentially, regardless of `$rating` being a value or null, it still creates and connects to a new `Rating` node. Any way to tell the system to only create if `$rating` exists? It looks like it just creates an empty node when `$rating` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this one was solved by passing in variables that were empty objects rather than Float type variables. Instead of having `{ create: { node: { value: $rating }}}` live in the mutation itself, I optionally send that entire thing when I send my variables. So if no $rating value exists, the mutation receives {} instead of a full create action with no value.